# Configuration properties bean is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a record like the following one bind to my `application.yml` file by the `@EnableConfigurationProperties({AppProperties.class})` annotation in the main class.

```java
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("converter")
public record AppProperties(/* properties */) {

    public record TableConfig(/* properties */) {
        //
    }
}
```

I also have a validator of the above properties that looks like this one:

```
@Component(EnableConfigurationProperties.VALIDATOR_BEAN_NAME)
public class AppPropertiesValidator implements Validator {
    // code skipped
}
```

When I run my Spring Boot application I see a warning like this:

```
2023-09-07T06:54:55.191+03:00  INFO 328 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesValidator' of type [x.x.x.config.AppPropertiesValidator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

How to fix it? I've read [**this**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying) article but can't figure out how this issue could be fixed in my case. Adding the `@Lazy` annotation into either the `AppProperties` or the `AppPropertiesValidator` doesn't help.

P.S. Spring Boot 3.1.3 and Java 17.

Comment: You cannot as it is used to validate properties which are processed very early in the process. It also doesn't seem right to use `EnableConfigurationProperties.VALIDATOR_BEAN_NAME` as the name as that will override the validation for all other properties as well. So not sure why you even added this one instead of just adding annotations to your configuration.

Comment: Just adding a Spring Bean that implements the `Validator` interface doesn't work. I have to name it as defined in the `EnableConfigurationProperties.VALIDATOR_BEAN_NAME`, i.e. as `configurationPropertiesValidator`. This is according to the Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: Still feels weird you should be able to just add validation anotation without a specific implementation of a validator. But alas. Regardless of that this bean will never be eligble for post processing because, as mentioned, this is loaded and constructed very very early in the process.

Comment: Nothing weird. Just `@Validated` annotation under the `AppProperties` enables only standard validations, defined by other annotations like `@NotBlank`, `@Size(min = 1)`, etc. In case of any custom validation you've to implement and define your own `configurationPropertiesValidator` Spring Bean.

Comment: You can just implement a JSR303 class validator for that as well without doing this specific validator.